# Powershell - Return a exit code ($LASTEXITCODE) to CommandLine (%errorlevel%)

Tags: powershell, cmd

I've got a powershell script called `exit_three.ps1` which does nothing other than `exit 3`.
If I would call this script from powershell I could get its return value by `$LASTEXITCODE`

But now, I want to call this script from CMD and get its return value (which is `3`) to the cmd-own `%errorlevel%` - variable.

I've read a lot of answers but no one seems to be easy to use / work for me.

Comment: If you run the PowerShell script from cmd, after running the command `echo %errorlevel%` should just print out that exit code, does it not?

Comment: My problem was that i used the `[ValidateSet("example1", "example2", "...")]` input parameter control and when calling the script from cmd with invalid parameters the script did not work and no error was returned too, so i thought the $LASTEXITCODE was not returned proper until i figured out that the `validateset` declaration did not trigger an error if the parameters are invalid ... Oo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%ERRORLEVEL%` environment variable contains the current `ERRORLEVEL` value, [automatically set when a program exits](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html).

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -c "& {D:\PShell\SO\exit_three.ps1}"
echo %errorlevel%
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Not surprising because `powershell.exe` default exit code is `0`…

Use either

```
powershell -noprofile -c "& {D:\PShell\SO\exit_three.ps1;exit $LASTEXITCODE}"
echo %errorlevel%
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

or<sup>1</sup>

```
(call )
powershell -noprofile -file D:\PShell\SO\exit_three.ps1
echo %errorlevel%
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Please note that `(call )` is here to set `ERRORLEVEL` to `0` (merely for debugging purposes):

Dave Benham in reply to [*setting ERRORLEVEL to 0*](https://superuser.com/a/649329/376602) question:
*If you want to force the `errorlevel` to `0`, then you can use this totally non-intuitive, but very effective syntax: `(call )`. The space after *call* is critical. If you want to set the errorlevel to 1, you can use `(call)`. It is critical that there not be any space after *call*.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Execute the Powershell-Script with the flag -file.

Following Script "test.ps1"

```
1
2
3
exit 4
```

Using:
`C:\>powershell -file test.ps1`

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Using:
`C:\>echo %ERRORLEVEL%`

Output:
`4`

This behaviour is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#exit).